# Как вызвать функцию инициализации перед загрузкой библиотеки?

Tags: c, elf, gcc

Сделать вызов с помощью атрибута constructor gcc

```
__attribute__ ((constructor))
void construct() {
    // Инициализация
}
```

не получается из-за флага -nostdlib. Есть ли другой способ (библиотека - чистый C)?

Answer (score 1):

Тут точь в точь ваш вопрос [How to run constructor even if “-nostdlib” option is defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760567/how-to-run-constructor-even-if-nostdlib-option-is-defined). Правда, ответы неутешительные.

А в документации по [dlopen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen) сказано следующее:

> **The obsolete symbols _init() and _fini()**
>
> The linker recognizes special symbols `_init` and `_fini`. If a dynamic library exports a routine named `_init`, then that code is executed after the loading, before `dlopen()` returns. If the dynamic library exports a routine named `_fini`, then that routine is called just before the library is unloaded. In case you need to avoid linking against the system startup files, this can be done by giving gcc the "-nostartfiles" parameter on the command line.
>
> Using these routines, or the gcc `-nostartfiles` or `-nostdlib` options, is not recommended. Their use may result in undesired behavior, since the constructor/destructor routines will not be executed (unless special measures are taken).
>
> Instead, libraries should export routines using the `__attribute__((constructor))` and `__attribute__((destructor))` function attributes. See the gcc info pages for information on these. Constructor routines are executed before `dlopen()` returns, and destructor routines are executed before `dlclose()` returns.

Так что, попробуйте копнуть в сторону _init and _fini.

Comment: Спасибо, а вопрос на SO - это мой вопрос и есть. :)